# How to add a function to DOM's top level to call it from developer's console (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is the code snippet:

```
<head>
    <script>
      function MyFunction (arg) {
        window.location.replace(window.location.origin + '/#/' + arg);
      }
    </script>
</head>
```

When I'm running it from developer's console, I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined(…)
```

How can I add this function to DOM's top level to run it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

you need to put the function code in developer's console and then call the function. like this:

```
function MyFunction (arg) {
    window.location.replace(window.location.origin + '/#/' + arg);
}; MyFunction("test");
```

Comment: What if I don't want to call it immediately (for example, if I don't know the value of argument at this moment)? Is it possible to make this function available from another places where this argument is known? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyFunction is not defined(…)
```

from this error means not find MyFunction in window object,
when you call MyFunction() ,will find this function at current scope,if not find,find the parent scope,in the end,find this function from window object.
you can like this:

```
window.MyFunction = function(arg) {
    window.location.replace(window.location.origin + '/#/' + arg);
  }
```

Comment: my command: window.GameBridgeRefresh
console's answer: undefined
my command: window.GameBridgeRefresh('123');
console's answer: Uncaught TypeError: window.GameBridgeRefresh is not a function(…)

Comment: before you use `GameBridgeRefresh ` function , you can defined this function.or not found this function at current window object

Comment: sorry, my bad :) I'm using a general naming like MyFunction instead of real function names here. Anyway, it doesn't work (at least in Chrome).

Comment: other reason,if this function in a closure,it not found this function in window object.anywhere not call this function except in closure

Comment: This function declared in SCRIPT tag (into HEAD element), and this function doesn't belong to any closure.

Comment: use f12,and ctrl+f to find the`MyFunction `  from page dom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121726/discussion-between-ying-yi-and-max).